# How to prevent the creation of a task item when the value of column Date is a Holiday

Tags: 2016, task-list

Using SharePoint 2016 on-premises and I have a task list where I would like to prevent the creation of new items when the value of column Date is a Holiday. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a validation formula. It can get quite long, depending on the number of holidays, and how far out into the future you want to go.

```
=NOT( OR( [TaskDate]=Date(2019,12,25),
          [TaskDate]=Date(2020,1,1),
          [TaskDate]=Date(2020,4,1)
        )
    )
```

You can also block weekend days in a similar manner:

```
=NOT( OR( WEEKDAY( [TaskDate], 2 )=6, WEEKDAY([TaskDate],2)=7 ) )
```

The "2" indicates that days are numbered and 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday).

Comment: I tested the first formula and it is still letting me enter items for those dates if the time is different than 12:00AM. The column is type Date and Time. I entered the formula in the column validation. what modification should I do to make it work for all times selected during those specific dates?

Comment: You didn't tell me about the times!  Replace each `[TaskDate]` with `FLOOR( [TaskDate], 1 )`.  This rounds down.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working now for any time selected

Answer (score 1):

One option coould be to use Column Validation, however it might be tricky to define a formula for 'holiday'
Another option could be to create an event receiver on ItemAdding, there you can check the date against a SPlist that defines the start and end date for holidays ( or similar setup)